# protobuf coredump when wrap dynamic generated message in function

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I meet a strange problem about dynamic create message using protobuf. as the code show bellow,  it works without error. but if I comment out the main function in the following way:

```
#if 0
    const Descriptor* desc = pb.pool()->FindMessageTypeByName("SvrRegRsp");
    DynamicMessageFactory factory;
    const Message *message = factory.GetPrototype(desc);
    Message *p_msg = message->New();
#endif
    Message* p_msg = get_msg(&pb);
```

it cores! It seems the mainly different is only wrapping the creation of message in the function. when i look up the call stack:

```
   (gdb) where
   #0  0x0000000001436ed0 in ?? ()
   #1  0x00007ff218c8f0e3 in google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Clear (message=0x1437aa0)
at google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc:133
   #2  0x00007ff218c3328b in InlineParseFromCodedStream (message=0x1437aa0, input=0x7ffc82fc3aa0)
at google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:131
   #3  InlineParseFromArray (message=0x1437aa0, size=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>)
at google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:143
   #4  google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray (this=0x1437aa0, data=<optimized out>, 
size=<optimized out>) at google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:207
   #5  0x000000000040137e in parse_msg (p_msg=0x1437aa0, 
buf=0x7ffc82fc3dc0 "\b\237\215\006\022\024QT-SIM-504761089-101", len=26) at pb_test.cpp:46
   #6  0x000000000040172d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffc82fc42c8) at pb_test.cpp:95
   (gdb) fr 1
   #1  0x00007ff218c8f0e3 in google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Clear (message=0x1437aa0)
at google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc:133
   133    reflection->ListFields(*message, &fields);
   (gdb) p reflection->ListFields
   Cannot take address of method ListFields.
```

It seems the ListFields is Null(pure virtual function call). can anyone help me to find out why does this happen? why does the code don't work when wrap the creation in the function. thanks in advance!

in file test.proto:

```
message SvrRegRsp{    
  required int32 RetCode = 1;
  required string SID = 2;
}
```

cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <string>

#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h>
#include <google/protobuf/dynamic_message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/importer.h>

using namespace google::protobuf;
using namespace google::protobuf::compiler;

enum {
    MAX_PACKET_LEN = 1024, 
};

int gen_msg(Importer* pb, char* buf, int* len)
{
    const Descriptor* desc = pb->pool()->FindMessageTypeByName("SvrRegRsp");
    DynamicMessageFactory factory;
    const Message *message = factory.GetPrototype(desc);
    Message *p_msg = message->New();
    const Reflection *reflection = p_msg->GetReflection();

    const FieldDescriptor *field =  desc->field(1);
    reflection->SetString(p_msg, field, "QT-SIM-504761089-101");

    field =  desc->field(0);
    reflection->SetInt32(p_msg, field, 99999);

    p_msg->SerializeToArray(buf, *len) ;
    *len = p_msg->ByteSize();

    std::string s = p_msg->DebugString();
    printf("req: %s\nsize: %d\n", s.c_str(), *len);

    return 0;
}

int parse_msg(Message* p_msg, const char* buf,  int len)
{
    if(p_msg) {
        p_msg->ParseFromArray(buf, len); // core here, because p_msg vptr is NULL.

        std::string s = p_msg->DebugString();
        printf("rsp2:\n%s\nsize: %d\n", s.c_str(), len);
    }

    return 0;
}

Message* get_msg(Importer* pb)
{
    const Descriptor* desc = pb->pool()->FindMessageTypeByName("SvrRegRsp");

    DynamicMessageFactory factory;
    const Message *message = factory.GetPrototype(desc);
    Message *p_msg = message->New();
    return p_msg;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char cwd[256] = {0};
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

    printf("cwd: %s\n", cwd);

    DiskSourceTree disk;
    disk.MapPath("", cwd);
    Importer pb(&disk, NULL);

     const FileDescriptor* file_desc = pb.Import("test.proto");
    if(!file_desc) {
        return -1;
    }

    char packet[MAX_PACKET_LEN] = {0};
    int len = MAX_PACKET_LEN;

    gen_msg(&pb, packet, &len);

//#if 0
    const Descriptor* desc = pb.pool()->FindMessageTypeByName("SvrRegRsp");
    DynamicMessageFactory factory;
    const Message *message = factory.GetPrototype(desc);
    Message *p_msg = message->New();
//#endif
//    Message* p_msg = get_msg(&pb);

    parse_msg(p_msg, packet, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the generated code of `factory.GetPrototype(desc);` and `message->New();`
If they are retaining the pointers and not releasing when returning to the caller,
then when the factory goes out of scope, they are getting destroyed and you are accessing dangling pointers.

Comment: Yes, the `DynamicMessageFactory` must outlive all messages created with it.